How to print from an iPad to HP8600 Officejet Pro without using Wi-Fi?
I have an HP 8600 OfficeJet Pro, an iPad and a Dell desktop. I can't print from the iPad using Bluetooth.
If I connect the printer to the desktop with a USB cable, could I then print from the iPad using the Bluetooth between the desktop and iPad?

If it has WiFi why don't you use just that?

As mentioned in the comments, WiFi would be the easiest way to print. However, as your printer is quite old, it may not support Airprint. It is possible that a firmware update can fix that, but I would would be very surprised if it did; companies (especially HP) do not add functionality with upgrades.
You may be able to transfer files from the iPad to the desktop using Bluetooth (does the desktop support Bluetooth?) Then you can print them from the desktop. Make sure Bluetooth is enabled on both devices and pair the devices. For more information see
https://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-connect-a-computer-and-an-ipad-with-bluetooth-a-step-by-step-guide/
Note that printing from directly the iPad via the Bluetooth connection to the desktop will not work.
